# Recover BIOS Password

Tags: windows-7, bios, toshiba-laptop

How can I reset or recover the BIOS password on a Toshiba Satellite l505?

I have tried the backdoor list and I don't see where the "jumper" is to use on this one?

I am unable to boot into Windows - this prompt displays @ boot, and if I enter an incorrect password 5 times it automatically shuts down.

It is an InsydeH2BIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find a CMOS reset jumper on any modern laptop.

I think you'll have to reset the BIOS.

- open the laptop, remove the CMOS battery and wait for the BIOS to reset to defaults.
- make sure you also disconnect battery and PSU for this to work
- after a while (1 or 2 minutes) plug everything back in and boot the machine back up.
- now go into BIOS and restore factory defaults to make sure settings allow you to boot. Then, optionally, re-set BIOS password to your liking.

Comment: Do you know how to dis-assemble the Toshiba Satellite L505?  I do not know where the CMOS battery is located or the best plan of attack to get to it :(

Comment: have a look at [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=toshiba+satellite+l505+disassembly). I think you'll be able to find something useful. I am unfamiliar with the particular model.

Comment: Most modern laptops store password in NVRAM which can not be reset by removing battery. You have to desolder the chip and clear it on a programmer device.

Comment: @nochkin - yeah the chip was soldered to the board so I was unable to remove it that way.  Desoldering the chip above my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all modern laptops (including Toshiba) store system password in the NVRAM (non-volatile RAM) which will keep the data even if you remove CMOS battery.
The only way to reset it is to desolder the chip and reprogram it or read the password from it (if it's not encrypted).

Some specific models allows you to bypass NVRAM data if you disable the chip by temporary shorting certain pins. You have to check the datasheet of the chip and analyze schematic to find the exact pins. However, this is not for an average user because you have a high risk to damage the whole motherboard if done incorrectly.

Also, some manufacturer's (Dell, for example) have the "master password" based on the serial or tag number of the laptop. You can call the manufacturer to find out, but they'll probably ask for a proof that you are the actual owner of the laptop.